# How Do I Replace Certain Characters From An Input With Others In Batch

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off

:TEST

set /p TEST=TEST: 

echo %TEST%

pause
```

If I take the above code and input something, for example "This Is A Test", how would I replace all of the spaces with another character, for example a plus sign or a dash?

Comment: Please use the [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search) function next time before asking a question! replacing substrings have been asked numerous times already...

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
@echo off

:TEST

set /p TEST=TEST: 

echo %TEST: =+%

pause
```